# auto numbering on a date change in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, increment, auto-increment

I would like to get auto incremental number in a data-frame whenever there is a change in a date.  Any recommendations please.
I would like the output as attached in screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Here is what you think though: will there be only one change in date? What if you have two things happen in a day? Can you skip days? Does that date always need to be the "today's" date?

Comment: There will be multiple transactions in a day.  I want to get a running number for each of these transactions - starting a fresh number each day.  Date is not required to be "today's" always. And no skip of the dates as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.assign(SINo=df.groupby('Date').cumcount()+1)

Date    SINo
0   2020-10-08  1
1   2020-10-24  1
2   2020-10-24  2
3   2020-10-24  3
4   2020-10-24  4
5   2020-10-31  1
6   2020-11-08  1
7   2020-11-19  1
8   2020-11-24  1
9   2020-11-24  2
10  2020-12-01  1
11  2020-12-05  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call your method that changes the date, just add 1 to the value of the SiNo of that respective row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to do what you need, that will work even if your dates are not sorted:

```
In [65]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]))                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [66]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[66]: 
    a
0   1
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   3
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5

In [67]: df['runlen'] = None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [68]: for v in df.a.unique(): 
    ...:     df.loc[df.a==v, 'runlen'] = range(1, df[df.a==v].shape[0]+1) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [69]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[69]: 
    a runlen
0   1      1
1   2      1
2   2      2
3   3      1
4   3      2
5   3      3
6   4      1
7   4      2
8   4      3
9   4      4
10  5      1
11  5      2
12  5      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
>>> df["SINo"] = df.groupby("Date").cumcount() + 1
>>> df
         Date  SINo
0  2020-10-08     1
1  2020-10-24     1
2  2020-10-24     2
3  2020-10-24     3
4  2020-10-24     4
5  2020-10-31     1
6  2020-11-08     1
7  2020-11-19     1
8  2020-11-24     1
9  2020-11-24     2
10 2020-12-01     1
11 2020-12-05     1
```